# How to choose contract address and wallet address

Tags: wallets, addresses, ico, cpp-ethereum

When you start an ICO, to receive a fund from people for your ICO, how do you choose the contract address and your wallet address to receive ETH collected for your ICO?
Thank you.
And excuse me for my bad English, i speak French, and i translate with Google

Comment: What do you mean by choose ? You can't choose the contract address, it's forged when you deploy it so you have to deploy first then you will have the address. Have a look at some tutorial like http://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/real-world-ico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when doing an ICO you create a smart contract that sends the tokens when you receive ether and when you want to withdraw an amount you make a function that can be called only by the owner of the contract.

Check out openzeppelin implementation:

[crowdsale template](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol)

Comment: in my ICO, I will not send the tokens every time I receive a contribution.
after the end of the ICO, I manually send to each of the contributors the tokens according to the ETHs received